# Transition matrices in $\mathbb{R}^n$: how to compute

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I was reading "Elementary Linear Algebra Applications" by Howard Anton, and in section 4.6, Change of Basis, it talks about finding the transition matrix, $P$, from an old basis $B$ to to another new basis $B'$. I understand that if the transition matrix satisfies $P_{B \to B'} B = B'$, then the the transition matrix can be found with $P_{B \to B'} = \{ [u_1']_B | [u_2']_B |\cdots | [u_n']_B \}$, where $u_i$ is the $i$th basis/column in $B'$ and $[v]_B$ is the vector's coordinates with respect to basis $B$.

The textbook then says this:

[image]

I don't understand how they got step 3, and i couldn't find a proof in the textbook... i don't see how simultaneously solving n systems is connected to this... what is the "same coefficient matrix" in the n systems? An explanation + proof would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The ***Step 2.*** row operations would reduce $\left[B' \mid B\right]$ to  $\left[I \mid \left(B'\right)^{-1}B\right] \overset ?= \left[I \mid P_{B\to B'}\right]$, but this seems not compatible with your definition that $P_{B\to B'} B = B'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row operations correspond to left multiplication by a matrix. Thus, performing row operations that turn $B'$ into $I$ is the same as left multiplying by $B'^{-1}$. If we do the same row operations to $B$, the result is $B'^{-1}B$.

Let $e_i$ be the vector $\left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ ... \\ 1 \\ ... \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right)$ with the $1$ at the $i$th position. Then $B e_i$ is the $i$th column of $B$, so $B$ changes the $B$ basis to the standard basis. Then, left multiplying by $B'^{-1}$ changes the standard basis to the $B'$ basis, so $B'^{-1}B$ changes from the $B$ basis to the $B'$ basis.

Comment: Oh great! Yeah i think i understand now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: there's a small error at "Then, $B^{-1}$ changes...", which i believe should be $B'^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I fixed it.